# SelectList paginada em Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

Tenho o seguinte código HTML para a lista:

```
<select data-placeholder="Origem" id="origemNew" (click)="SelecionaOrigem($event,oportunidadeNew.operacao,true)" class="chosen-select col-md-12">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of estabelecimentosOrigem" value="{{item.id}}" >{{ item.nome }}</option>
</select>
```

Onde os dados são carregados ao entrar na tela para "estabelecimentosOrigem" para popular a lista, porém hoje utiliza uma consulta que retorna todos os dados de uma só vez, deixando a tela lenta.

O que eu preciso é que utilizando um método paginado (já criado), ao chegar ao fim da lista o componente chame o método no arquivo .ts novamente para popular mais registros e assim sucessivamente para tornar o carregamento mais ágil.